# Folding the variable name

Tags: autohotkey

I want to folding tha variable name

code

```
numberOfInstNext := Array("","","","","","","","","","","") 

numberOfInstNext[1] := 777

i := 1
```

I tried

```
msgbox %numberOfInstNext[i]%
```

error:

> The following variable name contains an illegal character 'numberOfInstNext[i]'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the easiest and most scalable solution is to just assign a tmp variable each time you want to access an indexed array.

```
tmp := numberOfInstNext[i]
msgbox the value is %tmp%!
```

Answer (score 4):

**[Expressions](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Variables.htm#Expressions)** says

> An expression can be used in a parameter that does not directly
> support it by preceding the expression with a percent sign and a space or tab.
> This technique is often used to access arrays.

```
msgbox % numberOfInstNext[i]
```